# Pixelation with 50x50 profile pic and UIImageView

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview

Currently, when I insert a 50x50 image in an UIImageView and draw it on the screen, the image appears badly pixelated, is not smooth, and is not aesthetically pleasing. How should one change the interpolation algorithm UIImageView uses, to ensure high quality? I am also using SDWebImage to load the image from web, but that should be irrelevant.

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.gif"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resized the image to 200x200 pixels with kCGInterpolationHigh, and then inserted the image into UIImageView. The pic looks a lot better as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a imageView with a rectangle of 50x50 points.

There is a difference between points and pixels.
So you are probably placing an image with 50x50 pixels in the imageView with 50x50 points.

So for retina display your image should be twice as big to look smooth, in this case 100x100 pixels.

Comment: Sure, but if I look at the same 50x50 pixel image with Safari, and with my app, they look completely different, and the Safari-version is way smoother, even though they are of the same size.